# Access(or submit) a button inside a table <td> element using JS (greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a table where there are 4 buttons inside a "td"

i want to trigger those buttons from a 5th button outside the table

here is the code

thanks in advance

```js
function fn(){
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").childNodes;
    c[0].childNodes[1].click();
}
```

```html
<tr class="myclass">
   <td>
        <input type="button" value="a" onclick="alert('a')">
        <input type="button" value="b" onclick="alert('b')">
        <input type="button" value="c" onclick="alert('c')">
        <input type="button" value="d" onclick="alert('d')">
   </td>
</tr>

<br />

<button onClick="fn()">click</button>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want all the buttons to fire a click event when the 'click' button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

So, a few things are going on here.

#### 1. You are using `<tr>` outside of a `<table>` element.

Using `<tr>` without a `<table>` element is not valid accordingto the HTML specs. I haven't tested this too extensively, so the bahavior may vary per browser. However, the way Chrome and Firefox handles syntax errors like this is by stripping away all the invalid HTML, leaving you with:

```
<input value="a" onclick="alert('a')" type="button">
<input value="b" onclick="alert('b')" type="button">
<input value="c" onclick="alert('c')" type="button">
<input value="d" onclick="alert('d')" type="button">

<br>

<button onclick="fn()">click</button>
```

As you can see, this means the "myclass" element doesn't exist as far as the browser is aware. To fix this, simply wrap the `<tr>` inside a `<table>`.

#### 2. The `.getElementsByClassName` function returns an HTMLCollection object, not the element itself.

Unlike `document.getElementById`, the classnames alternative returns an array-like object called an `HTMLCollection` with the element that you want at index 0. This means that the `.childNodes` attribute doesn't exist on the result. There are multiple ways around this. The obvious way is by simply changing it to `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0]`. Alternatively, since you're only expecting one element with that class, you can also use `document.querySelector('.myclass')`, which returns the first element matching that selector. I personally recommend that version as it's more concise, but to maintain your original code as much as possible, I'm going to use the first solution for this rest of this answer.

#### 3. The `.childNodes` property includes text nodes.

If you log out the result if `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].childNodes`, you'll see that it returns a nodeList with `[#text, <td>, #text]`. You might be thinking, "I don't have any text directly in the td." Well, as it turns out, the whitespace we developers like to use to indent our HTML counts. So by selecting `c[0]`, you're actually getting the whitespace before the `<td>`. Instead, use `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].children`. Same goes for the click trigger; change that to `c[0].children[1].click();` (assuming you're trying to trigger the `b` button). Of course, you can also increase your indices on the childNodes to `c[1].childNodes[3]`, but I would strongly advise doing so as it offsets your selection significantly and may cause confusion in the future.

**All in all, your code should look something like this:**

```js
function fn(){
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].children;
    c[0].children[1].click();
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="myclass">
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="a" onclick="alert('a')">
            <input type="button" value="b" onclick="alert('b')">
            <input type="button" value="c" onclick="alert('c')">
            <input type="button" value="d" onclick="alert('d')">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<button onClick="fn()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below. I created a function to add a click event listener to each button. I modified your `fn` function to fire a click event on each button when executed. I believe this is what youre trying to achieve, but I can update the answer if this isnt expected behavior. Also, as pointed out by another user, `<tr>` should be within `<table>`.

```js
//get the buttons
var buttons = document.querySelector('.myclass').querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');

//add a click listener to each button
function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(this.value);
    });
  }
}

//fire click event for each button
function fn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].click();
  }
}

init();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="myclass">
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="a">
      <input type="button" value="b">
      <input type="button" value="c">
      <input type="button" value="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<button onClick="fn()">click</button>
```